# Why do they think the plot will work in "The Burnt Orange Heresy"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-burnt-orange-heresy

In [*The Burnt Orange Heresy*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8342680/) (2019), if James Figueras and Joseph Cassidy really want to have the final work of Jerome Debney, then they should kill him. Why do they think burning down the house and publish his final work (fake or not) before the incident will work and Jerome Debney won't publish more after that? What is exactly their plan?

Note: they don't know Jerome Debney will never publish anything before the day of the incident.